# iOS - ASINetworkQueue, requests continue to execute even after a request fails

Tags: ios, http, asihttprequest

I'm using ASINetworkQueue to execute multiple ASIHTTPRequests, and if any request fails I'd like the queue to cancel any pending requests and end.  From reading the docs this should be the default behaviour.  But I'm finding that even after a request fails, I still get 'requestStarted' for most of the remaining requests, and 'requestFailed' for all of them - is this how it is supposed to be?  I'm guessing it's maybe because my requests are quite small and the requests start before it has chance to cancel them once a failure is detected.  I tried implicitly setting setShouldCancelAllRequestsOnFailure:YES  but this made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the exact nature of your requests ... short answer: Yes, it's working how it's supposed to. Your requests are starting before a failure occurs. Longer answer: Try setting the queue's maxConcurrentOperationCount property. This may help you control the request pipeline a bit better if you need to test for failure.

Comment: Thanks for the info, and the tip for maxConcurrentOperationCount which could be useful.